# Unable to filter Excel web access web part

Tags: filter, excel-services, powerpivot

I have an excel web app with a pivot table that's data comes from a powerpivot SQL data source. I am trying to filter this data via basic 'choice web part'. when applying the filter i get an error message: 'An error occurred while attempting to set one or more of the parameters in this workbook.'

I have changed the data source to be just a table in the excel workbook and the filter works fine. So the issue only appears when using an SQL data source.

So my question is, is this a limitation of sharepoint or do i have an issue with my setup?

I am running sharepoint 2010, sql 2008 R2.

Thanks in advance!